# Force Windows 10 to install feature update via command-line

Tags: windows-10, power

I have a device that is ready to install a Windows 10 Feature Update (1607 from 1511).
The update was downloaded via Windows Update and is currently sitting resident in the system somewhere, waiting for the user to explicitly send it the command "Update and restart" via this menu:

[image: Windows 10: Update and restart option]

Notice that this is not a typical Windows 10 power menu; the options for "Restart" and "Shut Down" appear *alongside* the options for "Update and restart" and "Update and shut down". Normally (for quality updates) the "Restart" option is turned into the "Update and restart" option.

My specific scenario regards mass automation for use with an RMM tool. I need a way to push through a script via the command-line – language not strictly important – in such a way that the reboot requires no user interaction.

I need to force a reboot command to the device via the command-line that explicitly forces the system to enter "Update and restart" mode and not just "Restart" mode. I know of a tool called [ShutdownWithUpdates](https://dennisbabkin.com/utilities/) but it does not work for this (I tried); there is no functionality within the baked-in "Shutdown" tool either. Get-WUInstall does not appear to offer this functionality; certainly, it doesn't work when the update is already resident and downloaded on the system, which is the use case I am working towards.

**Screen macros are not an option.**

Comment: Why can’t you just click on “update and restart”?  Isn’t that the “super admin” modified start menu click anyways?  Which means the standard update and “shutdown”/“restart” should be present in the standard start menu.

Comment: That's just the normal start menu when there are updates queued and ready to go.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that the normal command line restart options trigger the update too. In this case, NOT installing the update and restarting via the command line is the more difficult/non-obvious thing to do.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "macros are not an option"? Do you mean you need a CLI one-liner? Macros are code used inside an application, usually MS Office. It's not common to refer to BATCH or PowerShell or VBScript as macros.

Comment: @Ramhound – the purpose is automation. I need a command that can be used across a large collection of systems without needing to visit each one individually. This will be used in conjunction with an RMM tool.

Comment: @music2myear – Normal command-line restart does NOT kick off an upgrade for a Feature Upgrade, only a Quality Update. The device will not install 1607 on a normal reboot, hence the two options in the menu. This is not typical behaviour, it is only for upgrades.
2) By "Macros are not an option" I mean screen macros that move the mouse and click on specific objects. Batch, PS, VBScript is fine, or a small command-line binary that does the same thing. This is how it will need to be done.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why a script is required? Are you planning to do this end masse? Also, I've run updates on several hundreds of machines up to current 1703, and I have seen this screen before. It is the normal screen for a feature update. Im guessing our difference of language is because you're quite a few versions behind and so haven't seen that screen as often as I have.

Comment: @music2myear I've already said the purpose is for automation with an RMM tool, so yes, rolling out the update "en masse" is the purpose. I will state again that the screen in OP - with "Restart" and "Update and restart" - is a-typical, and is only seen when a Feature Upgrade - eg, 1511 to 1607 - is queued, otherwise "Update and restart" is the only reboot-related feature. This is the crux of the issue - sending commands to reboot when Feature Upgrades are queued only reboots the system without forcing the Feature Upgrade process to take place.
I work extensively with devices from XP to 1709.

Comment: Ok, I see that in a comment you mentioned automation. Comments are non-permanent and all info necessary to solve should be added to the question itself by using the Edit button. The context of the question, the first two paragraph in fact, focus on a single system, leading me to ask that question. Please edit the question. Just adding a bit about wanting to automate this and removing the first two paragraphs more or less entirely would focus on what you're actually asking. Would it be accurate to state that you are, in essence, looking for a script to run a feature update?

Comment: The question states clearly "I need to force a reboot command to the device via the command-line that explicitly forces the system to enter "Update and restart" mode and not just "Restart" mode.". The question is fine. Your appraisal is correct.

Comment: @seagull - You have provided tons of information in your comments.  You should make sure that information is contained in the question body so the comments can be removed.  Your question does not mention automation, you having to perform something over a command prompt doesn't imply automation.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue and now I am about to give up and use setup.exe with upgrade option  to push the upgrade to estate.

Comment: That's what I've ended up having to do.